# Python loop to create csv from excel files in directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops

I am looping through a directory to update the external links in some workbooks and then its the goal to make csv's out of these. I have it functioning but instead of getting the name and path with .csv file suffix it just adds .csv to .xlsx

```
import os
import csv
import xlrd
import win32com.client

directory = (r'D:\\Dropbox (DBM Vircon)\\XX_Share Internal\\190826 - CD Refresh and Output CSVs')
suffix = '.csv'

for file in os.listdir(directory):
    filename = os.fsdecode(file)
    if filename.endswith(".xlsx"):

        wb = os.path.join(directory, filename)
        print (wb)
        clean = os.path.splitext(wb)
        xlapp = win32com.client.DispatchEx("Excel.Application")
        wb1 = xlapp.workbooks.open(wb)
        xlapp.Visible = False
        wb1.RefreshAll()
        print("refreshed")
        wb1.Save()
        xlapp.Quit()
        print("finished")


        wb1 = xlrd.open_workbook(wb)
        sh = wb1.sheet_by_index(0)
#Below just adds .csv to filename instead of getting name, then adding it 
        mycsv = os.path.join(directory, filename + suffix)
        mynewcsv = open(mycsv, 'w', newline='')
        wr = csv.writer(mynewcsv, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
        for rownum in range(sh.nrows):
            wr.writerow(sh.row_values(rownum))

        #mycsv.close()

        continue
    else:
        continue

file_obj = open("CSVUpdatecomplete.csv", 'w')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Separate the name from the extension with [os.path.splitext](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.splitext):

```
...
name, ext = os.path.splitext(filename)
mycsv = os.path.join(directory, name + suffix)
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `filename` includes `.xlsx` at the end, you will want to replace that with `.csv` rather than append.

For instance, use `filename.replace('.xlsx', '.csv')` instead of `filename + suffix`

Answer (score 0):

You can just use split function on filename:

```
mycsv = os.path.join(directory, filename.split(".")[0] + suffix)
```